# Query OS for hardware characteristics of wireless adapters

Tags: raspberry-pi, wireless, raspbian

I have a raspberry pi with 2 wireless adapters connected to it - one has an antenna.
http://www.modmypi.com/raspberry-pi/accessories/wifi-dongles/wifi-dongle-ultra-long-range-high-gain-w-5dbi-antenna

I am trying to write a script that queries my linux box for wireless interfaces, finds out which one is the one which has the antenna connected and put it into hotspot mode. Tomorrow, it can be any other adapter with an antenna attached.

Are there any tools or commands that can help?
Any entries in /proc or /sys that tell me this is the required device?
Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
Is there a CLI that gives the interface name and the Manufacturer and model?

Answer (score 0):

To know what wifi cards you have plugged in your system, run "iwconfig".
For the antenna, there is no way to know if your dongle has the antenna plugged on, or the antenna has been removed.
I guess, the best workaround could be, query the device for a network scan - then you count how many APs were found: if the antenna has been unplugged, you will not get any APs (or maybe only 1-2...)

Comment: iwconfig only shows the interface. Can a cli tell me what device is which one? I mean, something like wlan0 is Realtek adapter, wlan1 is intel centrino and wlan2 is ralink?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using hwinfo on my pi and doing the text/regex parsing in python to get all the data I was interested in.